# Normalising a vector with armadillo

Tags: c++, vector, normalization, armadillo

I created a 2 element vector that I wanted to normalise using the following procedure shown in the documentation, assuming I understood correctly:

```
  arma::vec V1(2) ;

  V1(0,0) = -2;
  V1(1,0) = -1;

  V1 = normalise(V1) ;
```

This, however, gives the following (to me, nonsensical) error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_wrapper_dasum_", referenced from:
  double arma::op_norm::vec_norm_1_direct_std<double> . 
 (arma::Mat<double> const&) in armaPrac-added5.o
  "_wrapper_dnrm2_", referenced from:
  double arma::op_norm::vec_norm_2_direct_std<double> . 
 (arma::Mat<double> const&) in armaPrac-added5.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to 
  see invocation)
```

Any advice would be gratefully recieved :)

Comment: Note that your title is highly misleading, as the problem have nothing to do with the actual normalization.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your point, could you suggest a better title? Also, I searched for an answer and did not find, could you direct me to the duplicate ?

Comment: (Just found the link, nevermind!)